# crontab nodification is taking too much time

Tags: cron

There are 300 processes configured in a single Linux server's crontab. if I want to stop or modify any of them, I have to comment them out (i.e. # ..cron..)  for all processes. It's a time consuming process.

Is there any way to avoid having to do this?

Answer (score 2):

#### Using a stop file

Whatever the cronjobs are, you could modify each of them (once!) to obey a global STOP-file, meaning: on every run, each of these jobs should check if e.g. a file `/path/to/stop-cronjobs` exists and if it does, do nothing. Use a pathname only the owner of the crontab can write to. If the job itself cannot be modified, do it in the crontab itself:

```
*/30 * * * *   [ -e $HOME/.stop ] || $HOME/bin/my-cronjob.pl
```

If you want to stop all these 300 cronjobs, create the STOP file and they won't execute.

#### Using vi

A completely different approach is to use the features that your editor of choice provides when editing the with `crontab -e`. Here, `vi` comes up and one could do `:%s/^/#/` to comment all jobs. And afterwards, to enable all jobs again: `:%s/^#//'`.